# Flutter Wordpress API POST -> Invalid comment content

Tags: wordpress, flutter

hey i'm trying to make a comment on a wordpress blog post but i get the error message:

"Response body: {"code":"rest_comment_content_invalid","message":"Invalid comment content.","data":{"status":400}}"

```
Map data = {
  "post": 47,
  "author_name": "peter",
  "author_email": "test@outlook.com",
  "content": "test comment",
};

void postData() async {
  final String apiUrl =
  "https://hui.bplaced.net/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=47";

  var res = await http.post(apiUrl, body: json.encode(data)).then((response) {
    print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
    print("Response body: ${response.body}");
    });
 print('ok');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i did it with paste content into the url:

https://hui.bplaced.net/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=47&content=helloworld